# Custom archive thumbnail instead of thumbnail from latest post (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

My (category) archive pages show the thumbnail from the latest post in that loop. Now I don't want that to happen and give my archive pages a standard thumbnail image. How can I do that?

In my header, I have:

```
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
      <div class="banner-image" <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>');"
          <?php } else { ?>
          style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bannershape.svg');" <?php } ?>
      </div>
```

But that doesn't work unfortunately. Does anyone know how I can have a standard thumbnail for my archive pages, instead of it showing the thumbnail from the latest post?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: 6/30/2020 -** I think I misread your question, so let me add more detail. On an archive type page there are number of [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), for example [is_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) (among others). You probably want one of those. You can go to the link above to see all your options if is_category() is not specfic enough for your situation.

**Option #1**

```php
if (is_category()) {
    $img_url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/bannershape.svg';
}
else {
    $img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post, 'full') ?: get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/bannershape.svg';
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-image" style="background-image:url('<?= $img_url ?>');"></div>
```

**Option #2 (a little less strict)**

```php
$default_img_url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/bannershape.svg';
$img_url = is_singular() && ($thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post, 'full')) ? $thumb_url : $default_img_url;
```

```html
<div class="banner-image" style="background-image:url('<?= $img_url ?>');"></div>
```

**Option #3**
Not sure, but based on what you're doing, you'd probably be fine with this one-liner

```php
$img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'full') ?: get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/bannershape.svg';
```

- `null` on `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` will just get the current page/post
- `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` "safely" (no erroring, via sanity checks already built-in for you) returns `FALSE` when $post is not found or $_thumbnail_id is not found
- `$a ?: $b` shorthand ternary for `$a ? $a : $b`

**Original Answer:** If you are on page, post, term, etc you can get the original queried object with the following two functions: [get_queried_object()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) or [get_queried_object_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/). This will give you either the $object of the current page/object (or post, term, etc), or $object_id of the current page(/etc), respectively.